# Hide images with excel filter

Tags: excel, vba, filtering

I have a table range that lists all products and a picture of the product is shown in one of the cells. When I filter the products, images of products removed by the filter end up behind other images rather than hiding them, or the images end up being shuffled to the bottom of the list, a bit like a "ghost" product, with just a picture and no info.

Is there an easy way to have these images disappear on filter? I assume there will be some way of doing this with VBA, to check intersect ranges and see if they are hidden, or by renaming the images to correspond to the product code and see if that is still visible, but is there a simpler way (as both those methods may well end up with me having to rewrite a fair chunk of code)

Example screnshots

Without filters:
[image: No Filters]

With filters (top row)
[image: Filters - top]

With filters (last row and "ghost")
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. Setting the images to move and size with cells will ensure they are hidden (I have done this through code when adding the picture by adding the line `.Placement = xlMoveAndSize`, but it can be done manually in the menus too.